# Windows 2016 powershell and NuGet Errors

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, package-management, powershell-v5.0, rdweb

I am trying to install the Windows 2016 RDWeb HTML5 client on a Windows 2016 RDGW server using these instructions from Microsoft [CLICK HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client-admin)

I was able to successfully do this on one of our regional server farms last week.

This week, performing the exact same steps, I am getting this error in the screenshot.

[image]

I then tested the command on my original server build and it is now generating this error as well.

Has anyone encountered this error as I am unable to find the cause? Also, I know it says to check my internet connection however, my RDWeb portal works but requires the HTML5 version or better in order to support Chromebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using TLS 1.0.  Try this first:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: THANKS!! that was the issue.